# For an Internet-only business, should I use the schema.org type Organization or LocalBusiness?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I have an Internet-only business and am trying to determine which `schema.org` type to use: [Organization](http://schema.org/Organization) or [LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness).

I did some research on Google and found that `LocalBusiness` appears to be a *subtype* of `Organization`. For an Internet-only business, would `Organization` be too broad? Or should I use `LocalBusiness` because it's more specific?

Schema.org defines `Organization` as:

> An organization such as a school, NGO, corporation, club, etc.

It defines `LocalBusiness` as:

> A particular physical business or branch of an organization. Examples
>   of LocalBusiness include a restaurant, a particular branch of a
>   restaurant chain, a branch of a bank, a medical practice, a club, a
>   bowling alley, etc.

Comment: `LocalBusiness` would only apply if you have a physical address and operate locally as well. If your business provides a specific service that you'd like to present as an _offer_, then you could consider using just the [Service](https://schema.org/Service) type. If you're only marking up business information however, it's fine to use `Organization` since that also provides the _makesOffer_ property.